# Swift MKMapItems distance from Users Location

Tags: swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager, mkmapitem, mkplacemark

Can someone please help me understand what I need to add to get the distance between the users location and the placemarks? I am just unsure what to change in the distanceLabel.text to make the number change to each Placemark. Thank You!

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ListedMapTableViewController: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var mapItems: [MKMapItem]!
var userLocation = CLLocationManager()
let distanceFormatter = MKDistanceFormatter()


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return mapItems.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "resultCell", for: indexPath) as! ListedTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let row = indexPath.row
    let item = mapItems[row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = item.name
    cell.detailLabel.text = item.phoneNumber
    let distanceInMeters : Double = self.userLocation.location!.distance(from: mapItems[row].placemark.location!)
    let distanceInMiles : Double = ((distanceInMeters.description as String).doubleValue * 0.00062137)
    cell.distanceLabel.text = "\(distanceInMiles.string(2)) miles away"

    return cell
}

 }


extension String {
var doubleValue: Double {
    return (self as NSString).doubleValue
}
}

//formats a double's decimal places
extension Double {
func string(_ fractionDigits:Int) -> String {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = fractionDigits
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = fractionDigits
    return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: fractionDigits))!
}
}
```

Comment: just had to change NSNumber(value: self))!

Answer (score 2):

CLLocation has a distanceFromLocation method so given two CLLocations:

```
CLLocationDistance distanceInMeters = [location1 distanceFromLocation:location2];
```

or in Swift 3:

//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

```
import CoreLocation


let coordinate₀ = CLLocation(latitude: 5.0, longitude: 5.0)
let coordinate₁ = CLLocation(latitude: 5.0, longitude: 3.0)

let distanceInMeters = coordinate₀.distance(from: coordinate₁) // result is in meters
```

you get here distance in meter so 1 miles = 1609 meter

```
if(distanceInMeters <= 1609)
 {
 // under 1 mile
 }
 else
{
 // out of 1 mile
 }
```